# Conditional Formatting Between Different Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column called Process Name, and another column called Sum. I want to create a conditional formatting that if the value in the sum corresponds to a certain number, it will change the color for the cell in Process Name

For example we have columns:

Process Name | Sum

process_1 | 2

process_2 | 5

I want to change the process_1 cell to color green because it has a value of 2 and process_2 cell to color red because it has a value of 5. I am able to do this when just dealing with 1 cell but I am not quite sure how to expand the code to dynamically reference the proper process name with the sum that corresponds to that process.

I have tried: `= $B$2 = 2` which is applied to Cell A2. I need to expand this so that for the next row it can use the same rule but expand to every single row below that as well. I know I will need to create multiple rules for different colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply CF to multiple the ref needs to start at the upper left cell and what you want to change(this case the row) needs to be relative(no $)

So Apply to the full column A: `$A:$A`

And use:

```
=$B1 = 2
```